# update JTable for a long running process

Tags: java, swing, jsoup

I am using the jsoup to get data from different URLs. I am trying to add them to my `JTable`. However it is only added after the entire thread completes, i.e. only after going through every URL, data is updated in `JTable`.

Here is what I do to update my `JTable`:

```
String rowData2[] = {title, city};
model.addRow(rowData2);
```

How can I make java to wait for updating this before moving on to next iteration of my loop for scraping data?

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you actually read the data? Shorten it if possible, removing irrelevant details. In which thread you are reading the data? AWT-EventQueue? Swing worker? Manually created thread?

Comment: I do this in a JFrame class in the main thread. I didn't create a separate thread for any of the operation. Similar to something we do in the main method of a JFrame class